# How to keep only empty elements in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array and i want to keep only blank values in array in php so how can i achieve that ?
My array is like

```
$array = array(0=>5,1=>6,2=>7,3=>'',4=>'');
```

so in result array

```
$array = array(3=>'',4=>'');
```

I want like this with existing keys.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array_filter.

```
function isBlank($arrayValue): bool
{
    return '' === $arrayValue;
}
$array = array(0 => 5, 1 => 6, 2 => 7, 3 => '', 4 => '');
var_dump(array_filter($array, 'isBlank'));
```

Comment: Or even allow the default for array_filter (which returns all non empty entries) and then array_diff it to get the reverse of that - `$array = array_diff($array, array_filter($array));`

Comment: wow mark that call logic can you post answer so i  can accept because its accepted solution that i want in single line

Comment: @Darshanambaliya - Louis-Marie's answer is a better answer generally, while my 1-liner is less intuitive, and may be faster for smaller arrays, but will be slower for larger arrays, and probably more memory hungry for larger arrays as well

Comment: Thanks @Louis-Marie Matthews

Answer (score 1):

there is likely a fancy built in function but I would:

```
foreach($arry as $k=>$v){
  if($v != ''){
    unset($arry[$k]);
  }
}
```

the problem is; you are not using an associative array so I am pretty sure the resulting values would be (from your example) `$array = array(0=>'',1=>'');`  so you would need to:

```
$newArry = array();
foreach($arry as $k=>$v){
  if($v == ''){
    $newArry[$k] = $v;
  }
}
```

Comment: hello @NappingRabbit can you please check mark baker comments its satisfy the solution in single statement.

Comment: @Darshanambaliya I saw it.  you are free to use whatever you like, but dont confuse `less code` with `better code`.  in this case it may go either way, but just because it is clever and concise, doesnt mean it is superior.  Often the elegant solution gives way to the practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

use for each loop like this

```
    foreach($array as $x=>$value)
    if($value=="")
{
   $save=array($x=>$value)
}
```

if you want print then use print_r in loop